# Exercise 8 on p.98 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres. Do we really need to assume that $B$ is closed?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> Exercise 8:
> Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:Q\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Show that if $f$ vanishes except on a *closed* set $B$ of measure zero, then $\int_Q f$ exists and equals zero.

My solution for exercise 8 is here:

> Since $B$ is closed in $Q$, $Q\setminus B$ is open in $Q$.
> So, if $\mathbf{x_0}\in Q\setminus B$, then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $\mathbf{x_0}$ such that $U\subset Q\setminus B$.
> If $\mathbf{x}\in U$, then $|f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{x_0})| = |0-0|<\epsilon$ for any positive real number $\epsilon$.
> So, $f$ is continuous at $\mathbf{x_0}$.
> Let $D$ be the set of points of $Q$ at which $f$ fails to be continuous.
> Then, $D\subset B$.
> By Theorem 11.1(a) on p.91, $D$ also has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> By Theorem 11.2 on p.93, $\int_Q f$ exists.
> By Theorem 11.3(a), $\int_Q f = 0$.

My question is here:
***Do we really need to assume that $B$ is closed?***

[image]

Comment: If $B$ is a countable dense set, and if $f$ vanishes on $B$ and is $1$ outside $B$, then $f$ is discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: It's because $B$ is closed that you know that $D\subseteq B$ .

Comment: @bof Thank you very much for your answer. $B:=Q\cap\mathbb{Q}^n$.$f(\mathbf{x})=1$ for $\mathbf{x}\in B$ and $f(\mathbf{x})=0$ for $\mathbf{x}\in Q\setminus B$.